# Why am I getting a row count of 1 in my DataGridView when nothing has been added?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a Form that contains a DataGridView. When I try to determine how many records are in the grid, the number seems to be out by 1. When the view is empty, `dgvName.RowCount` is giving me 1, and when there are 10 items displayed in the view, the `RowCount` gives me 11.

I checked my code to see if I was inserting a null row either before or after the table is populated with a query, but I'm not - at least not that I can see. Has anyone else had this problem? I can code around it, but I'd like to understand what's causing it.

Comment: That's the last Row, the NewRow, where you can input new data -- There's no *Visual Basic Form*, Windows Forms is a .Net platform, not related to a specific language

Comment: You shouldn't try to determine number of records from the UI. You should keep the data in a data structure behind the UI. The UI is only for user interaction

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm pretty new to coding on VIsual Studio. The examples I saw in the books I used as references pulled the data right into the DGV. You seem to be saying that my SQL query should put it into some kind of data structure and then copy that into the DGV? How would I do that?

Comment: The more straightforward method is to load a DataTable (e.g., using an [SqlDataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter)), then set the DataTable as the Datasource of your DGV. You then read the DataTables's `Rows.Count` Property

Comment: I'll look into that. In the meantime, your first comment where you said the new row was where you can input new data made me realize that I hadn't set the DGV properties properly. I still had the Allow User To Enter New Row (or something like that) to True. That's not what I want. When I changed that to False, the RowCount is now accurate. Thanks.